# Make flymd accept other file extensions

Tags: markdown, markdown-mode, previewing

When I try to preview my markdown files I get this aggressive funny response:

```
What’s wrong with you???! Don’t flyit if you are not viewing a markdown file.
```

But I am! ;-) It's just that I use .txt as extension for them. I'm even in `markdown-mode`.

Could I tell `flymd` that it's ok to try and preview these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the source of flymd, you need to add `\.txt\'` to the option `flymd-markdown-file-type` as well, using M-x `customize-option`.